# Visual force tag apex:map is not working

Tags: visualforce

"Unknown component apex:map " error is generated when i use visual force tag apex:map in my page. Is this tag limited to any particular edition?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Visualforce Mapping components are NOT available in Developer Edition Organizations. Please refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_maps.htm